# Override Lua instance function

Tags: lua, overriding

I'm trying to change the behavior of a Lua function, by adding code to the start or end of it. Because this is a mod for a game, I can't edit the function directly, so I have to override it instead. I accomplish this by storing a reference to the original function in a local variable, then redefining the function with my own, which calls the original one along with any prefix or postfix code I need to add, like so:

```
local base_exampleFunction = ExampleBaseGameClass.exampleFunction

function ExampleBaseGameClass.exampleFunction(param1, param2)

    --Prefix code goes here

    base_exampleFunction(param1, param2);

    --Postfix code goes here
    
end
```

This works fine for functions defined with the ClassName.functionName syntax, but some functions use ClassName:functionName instead, which from what I understand, are functions that pass a reference to the class instance as the first parameter. I can't figure out how to prefix/postfix these functions, as I get the following error when declaring a variable to hold the original function if I try the same approach:

`attempted index: exampleFunction of non-table: null`

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:` functions are just scary ways of saying "the first argument is `self`".

So, `ExampleBaseGameClass:exampleFunction(param2)` is equivelent to `ExampleBaseGameClass:exampleFunction(ExampleBaseGameClass, param2)`! It's just got `self` at the beginning, and functions declared with `:` will have an invisible `self` variable appear out of nowhere.

```lua
local a = {}
function a.b(self)
    print(self)
end
function a:c()
    print(self)
end

-- a.c(a) == a:c()
-- a:b() == a.b(a)
-- a:b() == a:c()
```

Using this idea, we can simply prepend an argument (it does not have to be called "self", it just has to be the first argument).

This **should** work, unless there is a part of your Lua environment (eg, funky metatables) which would prevent such a thing:

```lua
local base_exampleFunction = ExampleBaseGameClass.exampleFunction

function ExampleBaseGameClass.exampleFunction(self, param1, param2)

    --Prefix code goes here

    base_exampleFunction(self, param1, param2);

    --Postfix code goes here
    
end
```

The lua library takes advantage of the first argument being the calling object for it's string library. Notice how `("hello"):gsub()` works--by passing the string itself as the first argument!

Comment: The error I'm getting (attempted index: exampleFunction of non-table: null) happens right on the first line where the local variable is defined, so adding self to the overridden function doesn't solve the problem, though I assume that's also necessary given your explanation. Is there anything I need to change in the local variable declaration?

Comment: Are you sure that `ExampleBaseGameClass`'s equivalent in your scenario actually exists? Check for typos, as the error implies that `ExampleBaseGameClass` does not exist, instead of `exampleFunction`.

Comment: @PM4 then `ExampleBaseGameClass` is null at the point where you are running this code. This has nothing to do with `:` functions

Comment: Thanks! You're both right, the base game class is only initializing in server context, not client, whereas my override was running in both contexts, hence the error when launching the client.